# Angular reactive FormGroups loop

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms, angular-template

The goal is to have a dynamic component to automatically render required error messages for a given reactive form.

*.component.html*

```js
        <ng-template #errTpl let-control>
            <div *ngIf="control.value?.invalid && (control.value?.dirty || control.value?.touched)">
                <div *ngIf="control.value?.errors?.['required']" class="alert alert-danger">
                    {{ control.key | titlecase }} is required
                </div>
            </div>
        </ng-template>

        <div *ngFor="let control of signUpForm.controls | keyvalue">
                <div *ngIf="isFormGroup(signUpForm.get(control.key)); else elseBlock">
                    <!-- How to loop over controls? -->
                    <div *ngIf="signUpForm.get(control.key)['controls'] !== null">
                        ...
                    </div>
                </div>
                <ng-template #elseBlock>
                    <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="errTpl" [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ $implicit: control }">
                    </ng-container>
                </ng-template>
        </div>
```

Works fine when the form only has `FormControl`s, to handle `FormGroup`s, the following method is added to the component and used in the `*ngIf` above, to check what is handled.

*.component.ts*

```js
  isFormGroup(candidate: any) {
    return candidate instanceof FormGroup
  }
```

However, looping over the `FormGroup` controls, isn't working as desired.

Accessing:

```js
signUpForm.get(control.key)['controls']
```

Ends up in:

```
TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.
```

Even when wrapping the accessing into a conditional block, the same error message appears.

```js
<div *ngIf="signUpForm.get(control.key)['controls'] !== null">
    ...
</div>
```

How should the controls be accessed, to be able to pass them to the template in a loop.

Or is there even a better way to apply standard error messages without hardcoding each error message block, and without having to loop over each control?

### Additional ways to access the child controls (EDIT)

```js
signUpForm.get(control.key)!.controls
```

throws

```
TS2339: Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'.
```

---

```js
signUpForm.get(control.key)!['controls']
```

throws:

```
TS7052: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'AbstractControl' has no index signature. Did you mean to call 'get'?
```

Using `.get()` returns `null` again.

---

```js
<div *ngFor="let childControl of control.value!.value | keyvalue">
    {{childControl.value?.error}}
```

Using the above works to get the `childControl`, but trying to get the `erros` ends up in:

```
TS2571: Object is of type 'unknown'.
```

Comment: Can you try `signUpForm.get(control.key)!.controls`

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle throws `TS2339: Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'.`

Comment: Can you try `signUpForm.get(control.key)!.['controls]'` then ? (same as what you had but with the additional `!` )

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle please see the updated question for a documented list of tried ways to access the child control. Was able to get it with `control.value!.value`, but not able to get the `errors` of the child control.